# Profiling with Stack

Tags: debugging, haskell, profiling, haskell-stack

I'm trying to get profiling working in Stack, so that I can get the same metrics as the one indicated on [Chapter 25](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/profiling-and-optimization.html) of RWH. I started a new Stack project, as follows:

```
stack new test
```

Then, as indicated [here](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/master/doc/GUIDE.md#debugging) I ran:

```
stack install --executable-profiling --library-profiling --ghc-options="-rtsopts"
```

However this command fails with the following error:

```
    While constructing the BuildPlan the following exceptions were encountered:

--  While attempting to add dependency,
    Could not find package base in known packages

--  Failure when adding dependencies:    
      base: needed (>=4.7 && <5), stack configuration has no specified version (latest applicable is 4.9.0.0)
    needed for package test-0.1.0.0

Recommended action: try adding the following to your extra-deps in /home/damian/test/stack.yaml
- base-4.9.0.0

You may also want to try the 'stack solver' command
```

I've tried the recommendations above, without success.

If I run `stack build` then the program is built without errors.

As an additional question, I wonder whether is not possible to run `stack test` or `stack exec` with the flags above (this seems more logical than installing a the executable in order to profile it).

Comment: What happens when you try `stack build`?

Comment: Also, I've found that if you run `stack build` with the above options then it compiles the executable to a location under `.stack-work/` that you can run it from without installing it.

Comment: `stack build` builds the code without a problem. I forget to add that information, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me on `lts-6.4`.  To me, this indicates that you don't have a profiling version of base installed.  This would need to get installed when installing GHC.  What does `stack exec -- which ghc` say?  If ghc isn't located in your stack root, `~/.stack/programs`, then this means that you're using a custom GHC install, which may lack a profiling version of base.  To resolve, either:

1) Remove custom install and run "stack setup"
2) Alternatively, set `system-ghc: false` and run "stack setup"

Comment: This solved the problem. I was using the `ghc` located at `/usr/bin`. Then, after running stack build with the flags suggested by 
@Vaibhav I was able to get profiling information.

Answer (score 1):

`stack install` is equivalent to `stack build --copy-bins`, so you should be able to run

```
stack build --executable-profiling --library-profiling --ghc-options="-rtsopts"
```

which will result in a compiled executable somewhere underneath your `.stack-work/` directory (`stack` will tell you where). You should then be able to run it and get the `.prof` file you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

The only option that seems to work for me is:

`stack exec --profile NameOfYourAppGoesHere -- +RTS -p`