# How do I profile a Haskell application via stack ghci?

Tags: haskell-stack

I'm running `stack ghci --profile` (I determined this from https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#debugging) however I don't see any files generated that end with `.prof`?

Where is the profile data output to? Or how can I verify profiling is enabled?

Comment: I found a possible work around here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52804866/1663462